# How to count file size

Tags: java, tree, size, directory-structure, treenode

This method need to return a size of all files from directory and file size. To determine file size use `fileSize = tree.data.length();`, but when i want to count size of all files (files in directory and subdirectory) is a problem, because `fileSize += child.length();` count only files in a directory without subdirectory. I tried to use recursive method to count `fileSize += calculateFileSizes(child);`, but child is not TreeNode type and is imposible to cast. What I can do for count the size of all files in directory and subdirectories.

```
public static long calculateFileSize(TreeNode<File> tree) {
    long fileSize = 0;
    if (tree.data.isDirectory()) {
        File[] children = tree.data.listFiles();


        for (File child : children) {
            fileSize += child.length();
        }
    } else {
        fileSize = tree.data.length();
    }
    return fileSize;
}
```

Comment: `result.add(new StringBuilder().append(tree.data.getName() + " " + tree.data.length() + " bytes"));`

Comment: This work, but only for files, for directories don't work test. For test1 and inner1 don't show bytes.

Comment: Diretcories don't actually have a "size", you'd need to calculate it based on it's contents sizes